# Graph of a $G_\delta$-function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, reference-request

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a function.

It is well known that if $f$ is continuous ($f^{-1} [A]$ is closed whenever $A$ is closed), then its graph is closed in $\mathbb R ^2$.

Here is an analogous theorem:

> Suppose $f$ is $G_\delta$, i.e.,  $f^{-1}[A]$ is $G_\delta$ whenever
>   $A$ is closed. Then the graph of $f$ is $G_\delta$ in $\mathbb R ^2$.

It seems to be more complicated to prove, and I have not been able to find a good source.  So can you share a good reference or give a proof here? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each pair of disjoint open intervals $U,V\subset\mathbb{R}$ with rational endpoints, $f^{-1}(U)$ and $V$ are both $F_\sigma$, so $f^{-1}(U)\times V$ is an $F_\sigma$ subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Furthermore, since $U$ and $V$ are disjoint, $f^{-1}(U)\times V$ is disjoint from the graph of $f$.  I claim that $\bigcup_{(U,V)}f^{-1}(U)\times V$ is equal to the complement of the graph of $f$.  It follows that the complement of the graph is $F_\sigma$, so the graph is $G_\delta$.

To prove the claim, suppose $(x,y)$ is not in the graph of $f$; we wish to find disjoint open intervals $U$ and $V$ with rational endpoints such that $x\in f^{-1}(U)$ and $y\in V$.  But this just means we need $f(x)\in U$ and $y\in V$, and we can find such intervals $U$ and $V$ since $f(x)\neq y$.

Comment: Looks good. It looks like something similar would work if you replaced one or both copies of $\mathbb R$ with a separable/second countable metric space.  Does that sound right?

Comment: Yes, that would work.  More precisely, this argument is using only the fact the codomain of $f$ is a second-countable Hausdorff $G_\delta$ space.